# How to use Qt with Julia

Tags: qt, julia

Is it possibly to use the Qt toolkit with Julia? 
I've read that Julia supports calling c and python functions. How would I go about using pyqt/pyside or c's Qt bindings from within Julia?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most stable option right now is to call PySide via Python, for which there is already a [meta-wrapper](https://github.com/jverzani/PySide.jl) with some helpful functions (event loop integration, etc.).

Longer-term, there is a [C++ FFI](https://github.com/Keno/Cxx.jl) under development, and it has a [very minimal demo](https://github.com/Keno/Cxx.jl/blob/master/test/qttest.jl) of calling Qt directly from Julia. If you are feeling adventurous, this could be something to look at, but understand that it is still pre-release software so be prepared to file bugs and don't be surprised if some features are not available yet.